# Naming a view "Properties"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is a .NET  MVC 4 website using index for default.  So far everything has been fine for this site till I added a new view folder named "Properties", added an index view and created the controller plus a link on the nav bar for it. Everything compiles nicely.

When I run debug, and use the link, I get a 403.14 error trying to browse the directory. If I type the full route with the index it goes to the page correctly.  All link and code is as it should be.  I have not created any kind of model or form for this page yet.

When I rename the View and controllers to simply "Property"  everything works correctly.

Is "Properties" as a keyword to avoid?

Was I asleep that day in class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're running into this problem during local development? There's a physical directory called `Properties` in your project, which contains the `AssemblyInfo` file. When you're attempting to browse to `/Properties`, it would first look for a physical location, which it finds, then fail because it can't find a document in it.

If you publish this to a real web location, there won't be a `Properties` directory, so it should work. Or you can simply delete the directory and then it should work locally.

But personally, I wouldn't recommend that - just pick a different name. It's easier to just try to avoid conflicts like this whenever possible.

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue and I should know that. LOL. Thanks for reminding me!!